# I have the below python code, how can I use pandas instead of openpyxl?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe

```
from pathlib import Path
import shutil
import os
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
from openpyxl import load_workbook
os.chdir("D:/Project/Backup/")

path = "D:/Project/Backup/"
files = os.listdir(path)

for f in files: 
    wb = load_workbook(f)
    ws= wb.worksheets
    for name in ws:
        if (name.title.upper().strip() =='HI MAPPING'):
            name.title = 'HI Mapping'
        wb.save(f)
        if ('HI Mapping1' in name.title):
             name.title = 'HI Mapping'
        wb.save(f)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this answers your question :

```
for f in files:
    # Get workbook
    wb = pd.read_excel(f, None)  # None gets us all sheets otherwise pandas defaults to first sheet
    # Get all worksheets
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path + "newFile.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
    for sheetName in wb:
        ws = wb[sheetName]
        wsContent = ws.values.tolist()
        df = pd.DataFrame(wsContent)
        if sheetName.upper().strip() == 'HI MAPPING' or 'HI Mapping1' in sheetName:
            df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='HI Mapping', index=False)
        else:
            # Copy the data over to the new sheet
            df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheetName, index=False)
    writer.save()
```

Comment: The openpyxl is removing any images as its does not support yet, any other way to do this?

Comment: I believe it would work without the engine param, however one of two things will happen : 

1- It will write all in one sheet.
2- It will create duplicates

You could also use engine=None or engine=xlsxwriter. 
I encourage you to refer to the documentation : https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html

Comment: Yes I checked, tried combinations but getting only this error
ValueError: Excel file format cannot be determined, you must specify an engine manually.

Comment: Okay check out my new submission.

Comment: @ChirantanMandal , As you can see the code is updated, please try it out. Also, make sure the excell workbook is not open while the code is running.

Comment: This time it created the new file.xlsx for only one file in path but image is still removed

Comment: To have multiple files you just need to add a for loop for files inside the folder since, I thought you were only using it for one specific workbook. However, for images, I do not think there's another way, (at least I do not know) another way to keep the messages...